# removing the installed linux system from virtual box

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I installed a Linux system using virtual box on a Windows box. Is there a way to cleanly remove this Linux system from virtual box? I guess I only need to remove a folder containing this linux system created on virtual box. But I don't know where to find this folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove that virtual machine than right click on device list then select remove!! Here is image! U could just remove machine from Virtual box and can keep files for future or remove it completely also! [image]

Answer (score 0):

[Default folder](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html)

By default, this "machine folder" is placed in a common folder called "VirtualBox VMs", which VirtualBox creates in the current system user's home directory. The location of this home directory depends on the conventions of the host operating system:

On Windows, this is %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%; typically something like C:\Documents and Settings\Username.

On Mac OS X, this is /Users/username.

On Linux and Solaris, this is /home/username.